# CSS3 inset/inner drop shadow on input?

Tags: css

is there a way using CSS3 to get an inset/inner dropshadow on a text inputbox? The inset code below will only do boxes

```css
-moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
     box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000000;
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this - http://jsfiddle.net/3TYTt/

```css
input {
    -webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000;
       -moz-box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000;
            box-shadow:inset 0 0 10px #000;

    background: transparent;
}​
```